# Node bcrypt restrict hash length

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

Is it possible to restrict length of final hash while using [bcrypt js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs)

I can find options to specify salt length, but even playing with it keeps final hash around 60 chars

Need to hash password (capped at 20 chars) but hash is generated of 60 chars

Comment: Bcrypt is pretty clear in the doc that the hash is 60 characters. Third paragraph of the readme "The maximum input length is 72 bytes (note that UTF8 encoded characters use up to 4 bytes) and the length of generated hashes is 60 characters."

Comment: is there any other similar salt hash library for my requirement ?

Comment: Possibly, but it is going to be a really, really terrible hash, which would largely defeat the purpose of it. Keep in mind that base64 (which is what it comes back in) is a pretty "fat" format - 20 characters would only allow a 15-byte long hash. You could always just truncate what you get from bcrypt, but I am betting you will get a lot of collisions (e,g. both your password and mine hashing to the same 20 chars)

Comment: ya, not worth the trouble for the application am working on 
Thanks for helping out @barry-johnson

Comment: Happy to help. Have a nice weekend